# Stop communication

Tags: magento-1.9

How do I stop all communication from the Magento side like sending emails, newsletters etc.

I must stop the communication only if the customer is not active.

I already tried to look up for any configuration which can be used to achieve the above but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: Do you mean if customer not active then which things you want to stop?

Comment: If the customer is not active then we must stop emails, newsletters.

Comment: Define "active", has not been logged into for days?, Month? Years?  Is this just a one off exercise, eg deactive any customer not active before set date, or if the log in again after years of no activity, they get emails and newsletters?  If its the former would be easy compared to the latter

Comment: @PaddyD Magento allows us to put in active or inactive state. To my understanding it does not  depend upon the no of days, months or year. Also relogging in does not change this state. The state remains the same until it is changes explicitly in the account setting from admin side. Kindly list the steps for block the communication if a customer is in in-active state.

Comment: @upsla "Magento allows us to put in active or inactive state"  Magento does not have that option built in, sounds like you have an extension installed (maybe this one: https://github.com/Vinai/customer-activation, but it is no longer supported)